# What is the purpose of this for loop?

Tags: python

I'm following along with the book 'Black Hat Python' and the current activity is to build a netcat replacement. To set options, 'getopt' is used. I was confused as to why `o,a` is used in the for loop to check the options?

```
  if not len(sys.argv[1:]):
        usage()

    # read the command line options
    try:

           opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"hle:t:p:cu:", \
           ["help", "listen", "execute", "target", "port", "command", "upload"])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
           print(str(err))
           usage()

    for o,a in opts:
            if o in ("-h","--help"):
                    usage()
            elif o in ("-l", "--listen"):
                    listen = True
            elif o in ("-e", "--execute"):
                    execute = a
            elif o in ("-c", "--commandshell"):
                    command = True
            elif o in ("-u", "--upload"):
                    upload_destinaton = a
            elif o in ("-t", "--target"):
                    target = a
            elif o in ("-p", "--port"):
                    port = int(a)
            else:
                    assert False,"Unhandled Option"
```

Comment: `getopt` was never really intended for new code, but as an aid to porting existing programs that used the `getopt` library. You should use `argparse` for handling command-line options.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [documentation page for python getopt](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/getopt.html), there is an example that demonstrates this:

```
>>> import getopt
>>> args = '-a -b -cfoo -d bar a1 a2'.split()
>>> args
['-a', '-b', '-cfoo', '-d', 'bar', 'a1', 'a2']
>>> optlist, args = getopt.getopt(args, 'abc:d:')
>>> optlist
[('-a', ''), ('-b', ''), ('-c', 'foo'), ('-d', 'bar')]  # <--- HERE
>>> args
['a1', 'a2']
```

The `opts` (in your question) corresponds to the `optlist` in the example above.

`getopt` returns a list of tuples as the first return value (and a list as the second), so by using `for o,a in opts`, the code splits those tuples up during each loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

`opts` is a list of option, value pairs.  See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getopt.html):

> The return value consists of two elements: the first is a list of (option, value) pairs; the second is the list of program arguments left after the option list was stripped (this is a trailing slice of args). Each option-and-value pair returned has the option as its first element, prefixed with a hyphen for short options (e.g., '-x') or two hyphens for long options (e.g., '--long-option'), and the option argument as its second element, or an empty string if the option has no argument. The options occur in the list in the same order in which they were found, thus allowing multiple occurrences. Long and short options may be mixed.

So the for loop is processing each of the command line arguments, i.e. option, value pairs at a time.  The number of arguments can vary in number.

Are you interested in something more specific?

Comment: yeah, I was wondering why the options 'o' and 'a' were used. does 'o' signify something within getopt?

Comment: Ah, `o` and `a` are arbitrary variable names in the loop construct; they could just as well be `x` and `y`.  The important thing is that the `for` loop is assigning the two items from each 2-tuple in opts to them.  (opts is just a list of 2-tuples corresponding to option:value pairs as @Kingsley demonstrated above)